# find the angle between two vectors and check if the difference is between 45 degrees

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I have an object in the middle of screen that have a field of view of 90 degrees. It keeps rotating every frame about its origin.

There is a target object with random (x,y) vector. I want this target object to change to red color when it is inside the field of view of the object at the center of screen.
[image]

If you see the image above, the target is inside of field of view, then it must be changed to red color. But unfortunately I could not make this happen.

I have tried two formulas to achieve this:

```
1. Finding the arccos of the angle
θ = cos-1 [ (a. b) / (|a| |b|) ]

2. Finding the atang of the angle:
θ = atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x)
```

Here is the code of number 1:

```
let dotProduct = p5.Vector.dot(target, centerView)
let productMag = target.mag() * centerView.mag();
let result = dotProduct / productMag;
let angleInRad = acos(result);
if (angleInRad > HALF_FOV) {
  // Change target color to red
  fill(color(255, 0, 0))
}
```

Here is the code of number 2:

```
let diff = p5.Vector.sub(target, centerView);
let theta = atan2(diff.y, diff.x)
let result = theta
if (result < HALF_FOV && result > HALF_FOV * -1) {
  // Change target color to red
  fill(color(255, 0, 0))
}
```

When I run these codes, the target turns to red color, but it never changes when it is inside the field of view.

You can check and run my current code (p5.js) [here](https://editor.p5js.org/italoricardogeske/sketches/nc3i2y_uD).

Any ideas? Thank you

------UPDATE-------

Thanks to @MBo that show me how to fix this.
[Here](https://editor.p5js.org/italoricardogeske/sketches/BorTx-oEB) is the working example if someone want to check

Comment: Both examples look normal at the first glance. What is value of HALF_FOV? Should be Pi/4 radians, not 45 degrees.      (45*pi/180)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The HALF_FOV value is PI/4 radians.

Comment: OK. Now I see discrepancy between  codes - first makes red when angleInRad > HALF_FOV, while second - when angle is in range  -HALF_FOV.. HALF_FOV.

Comment: The conditions may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found error - you erroneously mixed points and vectors. Working variant :

```
 let targetvec = createVector(width - width / 4 - origin.x, height / 2 - origin.y)
  let centerViewvec = createVector(centerView.x - origin.x, centerView.y - origin.y)
  
   let dotProduct = p5.Vector.dot(targetvec, centerViewvec)
   let productMag = targetvec.mag() * centerViewvec.mag();
   let result = dotProduct / productMag;
   let angleInRad = acos(result);
  //  console.log(angleInRad)
   if (angleInRad < HALF_FOV) {
       fill(color(255, 0, 0))
   }
```

Note that it would better to store unit direction vectors if you work with directions a lot.